# Groupby add second column with aggregate function with a filter

Tags: sql, group-by, where-clause

Suppose I have two sql queries

query1:

```
select bF.MetricSubGroup_Level1, bF.MetricDisplayName, SUM(fDT.Weight) 'BASE'
from #factDataTemp fDT
  left join #brandFOM bF on fDT.BrandID =  bF.OptionId
where fDT.BrandID != 0 
  and bF.StudyName is not NULL
Group by bF.MetricSubGroup_Level1, bF.MetricDisplayName
```

query 2:

```
select bF.MetricSubGroup_Level1, bF.MetricDisplayName, SUM(fDT.Weight) 'Top 2 Box'
from #factDataTemp fDT
  left join #brandFOM bF on fDT.BrandID =  bF.OptionId
where fDT.BrandID != 0 
  and bF.StudyName is not NULL
  and fDT.AnsCode in (9,10)  
Group by bF.MetricSubGroup_Level1, bF.MetricDisplayName
```

where the only thing extra in second query is the condition    and fDT.AnsCode in (9,10)

and If I want to calculate both base and top 2 box in same query how to do it?

Comment: Why do `LEFT JOIN bf` and still have `... and bF.StudyName is not NULL`? That condition turns the LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `case` expression to do *conditional aggregation*, to get Top 2 Box:

```
select bF.MetricSubGroup_Level1, bF.MetricDisplayName,
       SUM(case when fDT.AnsCode in (9,10) then fDT.Weight else 0 end) 'Top 2 Box',
       SUM(fDT.Weight) 'BASE'
from #factDataTemp fDT
  left join #brandFOM bF on fDT.BrandID =  bF.OptionId
where fDT.BrandID != 0 
  and bF.StudyName is not NULL
Group by bF.MetricSubGroup_Level1, bF.MetricDisplayName
```